# Where's the NuGet package location in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, and am trying to figure out where NuGet packages are stored on my local machine.

I've installed the following NuGet packages:

```sh
nuget dapper 
nuget MicroOrm.Pocos.SqlGenerator
```

I want to replace one of the DLL's with my own compiled version, but I don't know where to put it. The `Dependencies` folder shows nothing.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

<del>For project.json</del> the nuget directory is in the user profile folder (`%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages`)

**UPDATE**

From [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)

> The global-packages folder is where NuGet installs any downloaded package. Each package is fully expanded into a subfolder that matches the package identifier and version number. Projects using the PackageReference format always use packages directly from this folder. When using the packages.config, packages are installed to the global-packages folder, then copied into the project's packages folder.

When using PackageReference, the `globalPackagesFolder` configuration value from [nuget.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section) is used. The default value is:

Windows: `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`

Mac/Linux: `~/.nuget/packages`

When using packages.config, the `repositoryPath` configuration value from [nuget.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section) is used. The default value is:

`$(Solutiondir)/packages`

Both locations (`globalPackagesFolder` and `repositoryPath`) can be overridden 
using the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable. The environment variable takes precedence over the configuration setting.

Comment: how do you get this location in MSBuild? before you would just do "..\..\packages\ "

Comment: well, you could do something like this `$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\`

Comment: I cant find project.json file @JuanM.Elosegui

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu Early versions of .NET Core used project.json files.  It was subsequently abandoned.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj

Answer (score 15):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-locals) documentation you can run this command which will list all Nuget folders on your machine:

```
dotnet nuget locals all -l
```

The result will be something like this (folder names self are explanatory):

```
C:\Users\...>dotnet nuget locals all -l
info : http-cache: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
info : global-packages: C:\Users\...\.nuget\packages\
info : temp: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch
info : plugins-cache: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\NuGet\plugins-cache
```